# Blocking Mac addresses in Linux Programmatically

Tags: linux, firewall, mac-address

Is it possible to programmatically block MAC addresses on Linux that are stored in a file?

Comment: What's the end goal? Protecting the Windows box from these mac addresses? This is not very secure. What prevents someone from spoofing their mac address? What prevents someone from using any other method to DOS your box? I see no reason to do what you're attempting. Mac address whitelisting can work in limited scenarios. Blacklisting is pretty useless.

Comment: I want to either allow mac addresses or to block them. What we are trying to do is a project for university. We are making a Wireless network using 3 laptops as access points . One of the laptops will be our Server and we will execute trilateration algorithm on it using c#. The mac addresses outside our specified area we want them to be blocked or allow the ones inside. Doesnt matter to us. But to do that we have to either block or allow mac addresses from accessing the network. That's our end goal. Is there an answer to what I asked above or a different way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can block traffic from specific MAC addresses using `iptables`. If the MACs are in a file `macs.txt`, you can add `iptables` rules to drop them with the `bash` one-liner:

```
while read mac; do iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source $mac -j DROP; done < macs.txt
```